# Video Modal keeps playing even after closing the window by clicking it on Mask

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I just used modal pop up to open a media file when i close that pop up it works fine in firefox but in IE8 and below, the display is gone but audio keeps on coming when trying to close by clicking on the mask. But gets closed when clicking on the close button. Have any one experienced similar issue?

I'm using jQuery verision 1.4.2.